# Enabling CMAKE_AUTORCC also enables CMAKE_AUTOMOC even if it's disabled

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012, cmake, moc, rcc

In CMakeLists.txt I explicitely set:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC OFF)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
```

However, I still get automoc project generated which is empty. If not using `AUTORCC`, there is no automoc project.

Does anybody know why it behaves like this and whether I can switch it off completely?

We are using `CMake 3.4`, `Qt 5.4`, `MS Visual Studio 2012`.